# Decoding after Passing JSON into PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Parsing JSON in PHP

My variable jsonvar is in the form of {"rating":"good"}

Once I push it through with this $.ajax code to submit, I'm a bit confused at what my PHP (jsonproc.php) should look like.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'jsonproc.php',
                data: {js:jsonvar},
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (j) {
                        if (j.ok){
                            alert(j.msg);
                        } else {
                            alert(j.msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I have it set up as

```
$decoded = $_GET['js'];
$response = array(
   'ok' => true, 
   'msg' => $decoded['rating']);
```

However when I echo it back,

```
   echo json_encode($response);
```

using alert(j.msg) shows a "null" value.

Assuming that I am passing JSON in correctly, how can I point to the rating and get the value of "good"?

Thanks

EDIT

SOLVED, USING $_REQUEST I was able to get the JSON, however $_GET did not work.

Also, the key was using $decoded->{'rating'} as $decoded is no longer just an array i don't think or rather it's a diff type of one?

Comment: You need to remove the "js=" from your AJAX script and then in PHP you will be able to access 'rating' from $_GET['rating']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing data types here:

```
 data: "js="+jsonvar,
```

jQuery will convert JSON if you pass an object, but you're mixing query string with JSON.

Try:

```
data: {js: jsonvar},
```

You may also need to do json_decode($_GET['js']).

edit: You can double check what jQuery is POSTing with Firebug/Web Inspector. Easiest way to know for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this to the top of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```